# Akka essential for Play

Tags: web-applications, playframework, akka

Just looking into play framework. Do I need to know AKKA first in order to fully utilize play. If not what would I be missing. 
 Should I learn AKKA first. Then Play or should I go the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would add:

1. you don't need AKKA in order to use Play, as AKKA is just a Play plugin
2. if you don't use AKKA, you will miss the Actors system and an interesting concurrency model as well
3. what you should learn first depends on what are you looking for: Play is a framework for web applications, AKKA is a toolkit providing you a message-based concurrency model

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to understand how these things fit in. Just another question not related to this title. Where does Netty fit in ?.

Comment: Netty is the HTTP server which comes in bundle with Play: it is based on JBoss.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to learn Akka in order to use Play.

Comment: What are the benefits if I learn akka first then play because the offical doc (play) says you can integrate akka with play. Thanks